# What part in my code is involved in restarting the game?

Tags: java

I need help understanding how to restart a game. I'm following a tutorial in the book Killer Game Programming in Java, and I want to restart a game without quitting and running the game again. I'm struggling with understanding what part of the code i have to reinitialize to start a new game. I'm trying to figure out a way that lets me keep my gamestats, but resetting the game. Now I'm only curios to know how to reset the game as I have no stats involved yet.

I have this a keylistener where I want to press "N" to restart the game.

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_N){
                newGame();
```

My question is What should the `newGame()` do to restart the game?

This code won't run, as I have tried to remove everything I don't think is relevant to my question.

Hope I didn't remove too much :S

Main Class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class WormChase extends JFrame implements WindowListener
{
  private WormPanel wp;        // where the worm is drawn


  public WormChase(long period)
  { super("The Worm Chase");
    makeGUI(period);

    pack();
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
  }  // end of WormChase() constructor



  // ----------------------------------------------------

  public static void main(String args[])
  { 
    int fps = DEFAULT_FPS;
    if (args.length != 0)
      fps = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    long period = (long) 1000.0/fps;
    System.out.println("fps: " + fps + "; period: " + period + " ms");

    new WormChase(period*1000000L);    // ms --> nanosecs 
  }


} // end of WormChase class
```

The second class

```
public class WormPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
  private static final int PWIDTH = 500;   // size of panel
  private static final int PHEIGHT = 400; 


  private Thread animator;           // the thread that performs the    animation

  private WormChase wcTop;
  private Worm fred;       // the worm
  private Obstacles obs;   // the obstacles

  public WormPanel(WormChase wc, long period)
  {
    wcTop = wc;
    this.period = period;

    // create game components

    addKeyListener( new KeyListener() {

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_N){
                newGame();
            }
    });
  }


  public void addNotify()
  // wait for the JPanel to be added to the JFrame before starting
  { super.addNotify();   // creates the peer
    startGame();         // start the thread
  }


  private void startGame()
  // initialise and start the thread 
  { 
    if (animator == null || !running) {
      animator = new Thread(this);
      animator.start();
    }
  } // end of startGame()


  private void newGame()
  // initialise and start the thread 
  { 

  public void run()
  /* The frames of the animation are drawn inside the while loop. */
  {

    running = true;

    while(running) {
      gameUpdate();
      gameRender();
      paintScreen();

    }

  }



}  // end of WormPanel class
```

Comment: Your code is way too incomplete to give any better advice than code according to [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and it should be pretty simple to start a new game.

Comment: Oh no, I was hoping I had simplified it enough! Well well

Comment: @paul also, thanks for setting me in the direction of MVC :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your key listener to the base class (WormChase) that starts the game, then you should make a method that initialize everything, just like the WormChase constructor, becouse that's what starts the game. So what you need to do exactly, is grab everything that's in the constructor, move it to method like "startGame" and in constructor call it. I'm now thinking, that you can keep the key listener in the window class, but you need to notice the base class, that you've ended the game in sence of restarting it. That means, the key listener when you press the N key, needs to kill the window that runs the game and notice the main thread that you're starting a new game. Which means you'll call the constructor again.

If you want to restart the game even without killing the window that's starting in main method, you need to think about everything that's set when the game starts and what values are there. Then you just create a method that sets everything to "start" values and then you just run the game.

That basically means recreate every object you have and use in the WormPanel class, like fred = new WormChase etc...

I'm really not a fan of nested functions so i would definetly try to avoid it  even Java doesn't support it (newGame()->run())

Comment: Hey thank you for this. I will need to experiment an re read your comment a couple of times to understand it all. Thank you for taking your time to answer this :)